# Azure DevOps grant repository access to pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am looking a way to give my pipelines access to repository. My goal is to create a script which would create a new branch and based on result merge the branch. I would not like to use my PAT token or my own identity for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions). You can navigate to Project Settings=>Repositories=>Choose specific repo to set the permissions of `ProjectName Build Service`:

[image]

**Note:** Azure devops doesn't support setting repos permissions for **one** specific build pipeline. If you grant the repos permissions to the Build Service, it actually grant the permissions to **all** build pipelines. You may need to  allow the related permissions like `Contribute, Contribute to pull requests, Create branch` to do what you want. Hope it helps :)

Update1:

[image]

Try using search box, enter the projectname to find the build service manually.

Comment: I have found that but I cannot find "myproject Build Service" I can only find project collection build service accounts but giving that access does not help.

Comment: @Kamsiinov Make sure you have at least one build pipeline(a simple build pipeline with a cmd task is enough), then this pipeline should use the source of  RepoA, run it. Now navigate to the page and to see if you can see the build service of project now. In addition: Are you using azure devops gits or other git repos?

Comment: I have one which I am using for testing this feature but I still do not see that "myproject Build Service"

Comment: Follow my steps to check if it helps: 1.Create a new classic Build pipeline, set repoA as its source, add a cmd task 2. Run the pipeline manually 3.Now navigate to project settings=>repositorys=> click repoA, still no project-level build service?

Comment: Did and still no project-level build service.

Comment: It however seems to work if I create a completely new project but not with the project I already have.

Comment: @Kamsiinov Maybe you can use the newly created project to test if my answer can help to resolve your original issue? It seems the strange behavior that you can't see build service is a completely different issue, I guess maybe it's related to the permission you have in current project? When you create a project, you're the project admin who has highest permissions in that project. But in your current project, you're not project admin?

Comment: I am organisation owner and project administrator on both projects (one that does not work and new one that does work) so it should not be because I do not have access.

Comment: It's quite strange, I can't reproduce same issue on my side :-( What about the test for the original question? If you give related repos permissions to the Project-level build service in newly created project, can it work to do what you want?

Comment: And to resolve the build service not found issue, feel free to create a new issue with details and Azure Devops tag. We'll help to check that :)

Comment: can confirm it works fine with the newly created project. would I need to have devops support plan to create issue?

Comment: Just create a new issue in SO with Azure-devops tag, that's enough~

Comment: Also, maybe you can try the search box? See my update1.

Comment: I did that as well but cannot find my projects build service account. I will create a new question to SO so hopefully you could help me with the problem.

Comment: You can share the link here and I would try to help that there if I have any idea :)

Comment: Continuing in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769810/azure-devops-project-level-build-service-does-not-come-visible-on-old-projects

Comment: @Kamsiinov I'm looking at it know, I'll share my idea there once I have any update for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213762/discussion-between-lance-li-msft-and-kamsiinov).