# Azure DevOps project level build service does not come visible on old projects

Tags: azure-devops

I have one older project in my Azure DevOps organisation that does not have this "project Build Service" account in `Project Settings=>Repos=>Security`. If I create a new project in my organisation then I can get it there just fine.

How could I get that project Build Service account to my older projects as well?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I get that project Build Service account to my older projects as well?

I am afraid there is out of box way to get that project Build Service account to your older projects.

As workaround, you could add a group for that project Build Service account on the `Organization Settings`->`Permissions`, add members in that group.

Then, go to `Project Settings`->`Teams`->select the `Team project`-> `Add users and/or groups`:

[image]

After that, we could search that group in the `Repos=>Security`, do some change in the permission and save it:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I created new team for project and added the "Project Collection Build Service" in there. Gave it enough access but the pipeline cannot still even create a branch.